# Get the email address of the user using a delegated GMail account?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm writing a GMail gadget, and was wondering if it was possible to get the email address of the user currently using the delegated account?

Currently, I retrieve the user's email with the technique described [in this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-apps-gadgets-api/d5xu_x16c6k).

But if I'm using a delegated account, it retrieves the delegated account's email address.

e.g. I am **john@example.com**, and I have a delegated account **admin@example.com**. When I access admin's gmail via delegation, I want to use the email `john@example.com` in the gadget, instead of `admin@example.com`.